# Automatically triggering a button

Tags: autoit

I am new to AutoIt. I want to run my code without hitting or pressing the "ok" button that appears when the `MsgBox` is called.

My code is as follows:

```
$val = 10
For $i = 1 To 59
     $doubled = MyDouble($val)
     sleep(100)
     MsgBox(0, "", $val & " doubled is " & $doubled )
     $val = $doubled
Next
    MsgBox(0,"the value  ","The final vaule is as  " & $val)
Exit
Func MyDouble($value)
     $value = $value * 2
     Return $value       
 EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timeout on the `MsgBox`.

From the AutoIt help...

```
MsgBox ( flag, "title", "text" [, timeout [, hwnd]] )
```

So you could do this to have a 1 second timeout:

```
MsgBox(0, "", $val & " doubled is " & $doubled, 1)
```

Comment: Ultimately a lower timeout would eventually have the same effect as removing the line.

Comment: @Mat The `timeout` value is in seconds, so 1 is the lowest you can go. A value of zero means no timeout.